# How to add Splash Screen on a Project that runs normally if you make it a JAR file

Tags: java, netbeans

My problem guys is if im adding splash screen on netbeans. There`s an error if you build the project to make it a JAR file. Is there a way for me to add a Splash Screen that works in a JAR file? Thanks in Advance guys.

[image: Here is my Property Panel]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it to the manifest.mf file above the line:

```
 X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

Then leave it up for a while in main method if you want:

```
 SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
 if(splash != null)
 {
    try 
    {                
        Thread.sleep(2000); //Leave Splash up for 2 seconds
        splash.close();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) { LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Spash Sleep Interrupted", e); }
 }
 else
 {
    LOG.info("Splash Screen is null");
 }
```

Or do something in another thread while main sleeps

Comment: Sir Richard can you tell me more? because im newbie in Java/Netbeans Development. all i do to add splash screen is in the pictures above. where i can find that build.xml to add that code and do i need to add the splash screen code on main or on the invoke run below on main function? thanks

Comment: It is under Files Tab - and no you do not need the code in main if you want to use the default delay for splash

Comment: ill put the code on manifest.mf or build.xml? if in build.xml, there a bunch of codes there where wil i put that code? thanks again

Comment: and by the way i dont have any codes for splash screen like that. All i do is in the picture above sir Richard thanks

Comment: I can see I was confusing you.  The code I have is for packaging libraries into a single jar with with the application.  I have edited my response. You just have the line in the wrong location in the manifest.mf file.